# How do I convert UIPageViewController content to UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I currently have an on-boarding section of an app with six ViewControllers inside a UIPageViewController. Because of the limitations of UIPageViewController, I would like to change to using UIScrollView so I can take full advantage of paging along with the UIScrollView delegate methods.

The Views are all built using Storyboards so I need to figure out how to bring them into a UIScrollView with paging enabled. All the references I have found show how to create views inside a UIScrollView programmatically like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    let colors = [UIColor.cyan, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]
    var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 , width: 0, height: 0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for index in 0..<colors.count {
            frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

            let subView = UIView(frame: frame)
            subView.backgroundColor = colors[index]
            scrollView.addSubview(subView)
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(colors.count), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

    }
}
```

How do I bring in the Views created in Storyboards into the UIScrollView?

Running Xcode 11.

Comment: First, use auto-layout constraints instead of explicit frame sizes. Second, load the view controllers as child view controllers, and add their views to the scrollview.

Comment: @DonMag Your brevity has its merits, but more detail would be very helpful for someone that is still heavily dependent on tutorials for learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started...

The basic idea is:

- create your "main" view controller with a `UIScrollView` and a `UIPageControl`

  - arrange and constrain them as normal
- add a `UIStackView` to the scroll view

  - constrain Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom - all at Zero - to the scroll view's Content Layout Guide
  - constrain the stack view's Height equal to the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide Height
  - constrain the stack view's Width equal to the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide Width, with a Priority of 250 (so we can extend it horizontally)
- create your "page" view controllers as normal (if you were using a `UIPageViewController` you can use the same VCs)

In your code, you will:

- instantiate each "page" view controller using `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboard id")`
- add each VC's view to the stack view
- set each VC's view's height and width constraints equal to the scroll view's height and width
- add each VC as a child view controller

Here is example code:

```
//
//  ScrollChildrenViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/2/19.
//

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
}

class ScrollChildrenViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let firstVC  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC"),
            let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC"),
            let thirdVC  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdVC") {

            [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC].forEach {
                vc in
                vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(vc.view)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
                    vc.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor),
                ])
                self.addChild(vc)
                vc.didMove(toParent: self)
            }

        }

        pageControl.numberOfPages = stackView.arrangedSubviews.count

        scrollView.delegate = self

    }

    @IBAction func changePage(_ sender: Any) {
        let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:x, y:0), animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }

}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

And here is the source of the Storyboard I used (matches the IB connections and storyboard IDs for the above code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14868" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="HA6-Hm-gNO">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14824"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Scroll Children View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="FeD-sX-zkf">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="HA6-Hm-gNO" customClass="ScrollChildrenViewController" customModule="X11SwiftScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="guw-AN-V6Z">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" pagingEnabled="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="AJV-iC-aAl">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="335" height="570"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aG7-ac-pRi">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="335" height="570"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="aG7-ac-pRi" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="AJV-iC-aAl" secondAttribute="leading" id="3Nf-2e-Lvd"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="aG7-ac-pRi" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="QBH-AA-ldV" secondAttribute="width" priority="250" id="73U-dy-cDC"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="aG7-ac-pRi" secondAttribute="bottom" id="c4T-p7-smf"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="aG7-ac-pRi" secondAttribute="trailing" id="fcJ-yI-Rhr"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="aG7-ac-pRi" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="QBH-AA-ldV" secondAttribute="height" id="lev-mF-lqF"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="aG7-ac-pRi" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="QBH-AA-ldV" secondAttribute="top" id="r17-FW-2AS"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="y7N-I3-1Zo"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="QBH-AA-ldV"/>
                            </scrollView>
                            <pageControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" numberOfPages="3" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wbc-5i-RSa">
                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="610" width="295" height="37"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.33333333333333331" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="37" id="Mnd-Q4-F8P"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="changePage:" destination="HA6-Hm-gNO" eventType="valueChanged" id="fjQ-Wa-gcL"/>
                                </connections>
                            </pageControl>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor" red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="wbc-5i-RSa" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="AJV-iC-aAl" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="7Ry-XJ-xei"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="vZA-Us-fWZ" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wbc-5i-RSa" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="M1u-ay-zwW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="vZA-Us-fWZ" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="AJV-iC-aAl" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="TFB-sw-TS8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="vZA-Us-fWZ" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wbc-5i-RSa" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="Z9x-TT-Qp2"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="AJV-iC-aAl" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vZA-Us-fWZ" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="h6y-ZT-gOJ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="AJV-iC-aAl" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vZA-Us-fWZ" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="hsS-4R-mJN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="wbc-5i-RSa" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vZA-Us-fWZ" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="pnQ-HO-wog"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vZA-Us-fWZ"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="pageControl" destination="wbc-5i-RSa" id="Jp4-bx-MON"/>
                        <outlet property="scrollView" destination="AJV-iC-aAl" id="gRc-d1-ovk"/>
                        <outlet property="stackView" destination="aG7-ac-pRi" id="A7K-p6-0qb"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="IcG-Qh-9Bs" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="97" y="101"/>
        </scene>
        <!--First View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="6lF-tN-5dp">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="FirstVC" id="UGA-X4-xWu" customClass="FirstViewController" customModule="X11SwiftScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Cbg-Bf-5of">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="First" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="QpL-Cz-Cyz">
                                <rect key="frame" x="75" y="167" width="225" height="333.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="34"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemRedColor" red="1" green="0.23137254900000001" blue="0.18823529410000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="QpL-Cz-Cyz" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Cbg-Bf-5of" secondAttribute="centerY" id="KfQ-r8-wAh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QpL-Cz-Cyz" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="Z13-Ky-FK3" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.5" id="LcM-2k-rx2"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QpL-Cz-Cyz" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Cbg-Bf-5of" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Yrm-dS-0f5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QpL-Cz-Cyz" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Z13-Ky-FK3" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.6" id="ZZA-ZB-a0f"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Z13-Ky-FK3"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="B2Z-Uu-lBa" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="751" y="100"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Second View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="GUP-16-paa">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="SecondVC" id="Zqm-Ha-81P" customClass="SecondViewController" customModule="X11SwiftScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="F6j-rn-0IC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Second" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="LNi-xp-nA8">
                                <rect key="frame" x="75" y="167" width="225" height="333.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="34"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGreenColor" red="0.20392156859999999" green="0.78039215689999997" blue="0.34901960780000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="LNi-xp-nA8" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="F6j-rn-0IC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="6tP-P6-OWb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="LNi-xp-nA8" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="scO-8f-hyo" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.6" id="AFz-Rh-Uqp"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="LNi-xp-nA8" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="scO-8f-hyo" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.5" id="Kb2-i6-5cq"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="LNi-xp-nA8" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="F6j-rn-0IC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Vhi-Ml-T71"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="scO-8f-hyo"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="oOe-A7-SKt" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1399" y="99"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Third View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="IRH-Pv-biB">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ThirdVC" id="moo-RP-Ao6" customClass="ThirdViewController" customModule="X11SwiftScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="29I-Jb-Oxe">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Third" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bqa-p6-6PN">
                                <rect key="frame" x="75" y="167" width="225" height="333.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="34"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBlueColor" red="0.0" green="0.47843137250000001" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="bqa-p6-6PN" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="uvx-3l-6lL" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.5" id="3wA-wk-XA4"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="bqa-p6-6PN" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="29I-Jb-Oxe" secondAttribute="centerX" id="4ie-qL-hRk"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="bqa-p6-6PN" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="uvx-3l-6lL" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.6" id="7fh-8L-PGY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="bqa-p6-6PN" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="29I-Jb-Oxe" secondAttribute="centerY" id="O3M-zi-oGO"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="uvx-3l-6lL"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="GGY-3Y-kct" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="2062" y="99"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

**Note:**

It's worth pointing out... While this effectively replicates the behavior of a `UIPageViewController`, you have lost all of the built-in memory management.

If you only have a couple "pages," no big deal... but if you have a large number of "pages," I guess you should weigh that against whatever benefit you would get from this approach (vs a `UIPageViewController`).

Comment: If I were in charge of the pearly gates I would give you entrance to heaven for this post. Thank you so so much for the time you took to do this. I really appreciate it. I have been working and searching for days trying to figure this out. You're the best.

Comment: Quick followup. How do I set the scrollView.delegate = self for the UIViewContollers inside the scrollView? I am trying to trigger animations within each View but can't set the delegate. Any ideas?

Comment: A scroll view can have only one delegate... What you probably want to do is set the "main" VC as the delegate and then pass along scroll events to the children.